# Timer counts but doesn´t desplay

Tags: swift, timer

I just started to learn how to code and speak English^^

When I go from secondViewController to ViewController, a timer starts. A label shows the timer.

My problem is, when I go from secondViewController to ViewController for the second time, the label doesn´t show the timer. But the timer continue to count (I printed it out). Why the label doesn´t shoews the timer ?

I would be very grateful for your help

**ViewController**

```
var habit = 0
var statusFirst = false
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var firstTitel = ""
    var secondTitels = ""
    var timerTime = 0
    var timer = Timer()

    @IBOutlet weak var titelLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var secondTitel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondDate: UILabel!

    @objc func processTimer() {

        timerTime += 1
        dateLabel.text = String(timerTime)
        print(timerTime)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Hide Label - START
        print(habit)
        if habit == 0 {
            titelLabel.isHidden = true
            secondTitel.isHidden = true

            dateLabel.isHidden = true
            secondDate.isHidden = true

            timer.invalidate()

        }else if habit == 1 {
            titelLabel.isHidden = false
            secondTitel.isHidden = true

            dateLabel.isHidden = false
            secondDate.isHidden = true

            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.processTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        }else if habit == 2 {
            titelLabel.isHidden = false
            secondTitel.isHidden = false

            dateLabel.isHidden = false
            secondDate.isHidden = false
        }
        // Hide Label - END

            let titelObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "firstTitel")

            if let titel = titelObject as? String {

                titelLabel.text = titel

            }

            let titellObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "secondTitel")

            if let titell = titellObject as? String {

                secondTitel.text = titell

            }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

**SecondViewController**

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var titelSecondViewController = ""
    var dateSecondViewController = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var titelField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateField: UITextField!


    @IBOutlet weak var okButton: UIButton!
    @IBAction func okButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {

        titelSecondViewController = titelField.text!

        if let datefield = dateField.text {
            if datefield == "" {
                dateSecondViewController = 0
            }else{
                dateSecondViewController = Int(datefield)!
            }
        }else{
            print("lol")
        }
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }


    // Segue - Start

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "toViewController" {

            let viewController = segue.destination as! ViewController

            habit += 1
            print(habit)
            if habit == 1 {
                statusFirst = true
                UserDefaults.standard.set(titelSecondViewController, forKey: "firstTitel")


            }else if habit == 2{

                UserDefaults.standard.set(titelSecondViewController, forKey: "secondTitel")


            }else{
                return
            }
        }
    }

    // Segue - End



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: ‘print(“lol”)’ hahaha

Comment: hhahahahahha xD

Answer (score 0):

In first case `habit = 1` so the timer is called

```
 timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.processTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

since the timer has a strong reference and you don't `invalidate()` it inside `viewDidDisappear` , it keeps the VC in memory after you dismiss it

//

In second time `habit = 2` and you don't init the time inside it's if statement then the label of the second instance ( the presented one ) doesn't update , while the hidden dismissed one do

Comment: Hey Sh_Kahn and thank you very much for your answer ! But I still do not understand what to do :(